# Canadian and USA Administrative Boundary Data Service

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, canada

I have a list of place names (300+), which are mostly cites and states/provinces in United States and Canada. I would like to get the administrative boundary for them. I know the raw boundary data is downloadable from the government website but I wonder if there is any convenient service to search and download using API or a UI.

Comment: Does openstreetmap.org not have this?

Comment: @BarryCarter I have tested a few places. Not all of them have the administrative boundary added in OSM.

Comment: You can get Canadian boundary files from https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-eng.cfm I did a comparison between this and gadm.com below and the ones from statcan seem to be a bit more detailed. I believe you can also use statcan data commercially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet for up-to-date boundary files at the provincial/state and municipal/county level for the world is the [Global Administrative Boundaries](http://gadm.org/) Project. Unless you're looking for a specific Canadian/American boundary type (Economic Regions, Special Counties?) this data set should be fine. All data can be downloaded directly through their website.

Alternatively, if you're working in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/), the 'sp' package fully integrates the GADM data, offering an API-like method for downloading and presenting the data. More info on how to do that can be found in the GIS SE (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30024321)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this very comprehensive dataset. Also thank you for mentioning the R package. It's of great help.